# Filter SQL result using XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have created the following piece of code to ensure that I can filter certain dimension using a comma delimited parameter:

```
DECLARE @Dimension NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Dimension = 'Average Life,Coupon Frequency'

DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Dimension, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)

SELECT d.* 
FROM Dim_Security_Analytics as d
INNER JOIN @XML.nodes('i') x(i) 
    ON  d.dimension = x.i.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
WHERE d.Date = '2018-12-31'
```

However when a '' or a NULL is passed in the @Dimension parameter I would like all dimensions to be returned.  I'm unsure as to how I can code for this in the XML as this is pretty new to me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Best, performance-wise: do an `IF` and write the query again without the `JOIN`. Alternative: add `OR @XML IS NULL` to the `ON` condition, and do not assign it if `@Dimension` is `NULL` or `''`. There are also [alternatives](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) to using XML in this case, and there are [other things to consider](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) if you have many parameters like this.

Comment: I would avoid messing around with comma delimited strings in SQL whenever possible and use a table valued parameter instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use `STRING_SPLIT` (requires SQL Server 2016 or later):

```sql
DECLARE @Dimension NVARCHAR(100) = 'Average Life,Coupon Frequency';

SELECT *
FROM Dim_Security_Analytics
WHERE Date = '2018-12-31'
AND (@Dimension IS NULL OR dimension IN (
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Dimension, ',')
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @Dimension NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Dimension = 'Average Life,Coupon Frequency'

DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Dimension, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)

DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100), dimension NVARCHAR(MAX),[Date] DATE);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('First row','missing dimension','2018-12-31')
                         ,('second row','Average Life','2018-12-31')
                         ,('third row','Coupon Frequency','2018-12-31')
                         ,('fourth row',NULL,'2018-12-31');

SELECT d.* 
FROM @mockup as d
WHERE d.Date = '2018-12-31' 
  AND (@Dimension IS NULL OR LEN(@Dimension) = 0 OR @XML.exist('/i[text()=sql:column("dimension")]')=1);
```

Instead of an `INNER JOIN` we shift the logic to the `WHERE`.

It might be faster to use a declared table-variabe which you fill out of your XML (instead of working with the XML directly).